# get all tablles in database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get all tables in database using VB.NET using this script

```vb
Public Sub GetTable(ByVal combodata As ComboBox, ByVal listtable As DataGridView)
    'Try
    dt.Clear()
    Dim ServerConnection As ServerConnection = Nothing
    If combodata.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("You Do Not Choose The DataBase Name", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim objCn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    ServerConnection = New ServerConnection(objCn)
    Dim server As New Server(ServerConnection)
    Dim objtables As TableCollection = server.Databases(DataBaseName).Tables
    If objtables.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You Do Not Choose The DataBase Name", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        combodata.Focus()
    End If
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT name as 'Table Name' FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'u' ORDER BY Name", objCn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    listtable.DataSource = dt
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

but I have error in this line

```vb
Dim objtables As TableCollection = server.Databases(DataBaseName).Tables
```

The error is:

> Failed to connect to server.

I don't know why it happens ..my script is correct

Comment: Debug ConnectionString...is it correct?

Comment: Are you able to connect using the same credentials thru' SSMS - SQL Server Management Studio? Have you missed opening the connection before querying DB?

Comment: i change  ComboDataBase_SelectedIndexChanged with ComboDataBase_TextChanged to gat the database and is worked thank you for all

Comment: `my script is correct` - on contrary, your script is wrong on too many levels.

Comment: @GSerg, so explain to them *why* it's `wrong on too many levels.`

Comment: @AlexM. I'm afraid to miss some levels. Absence of `Using`; unnecessary use of SQL DMO when the last query is all that is needed; use of global variables; poor separation of concerns, mixing interface and backend; comparing to `Nothing` using `=` instead of `Is`; using the deprecated `dbo.sysobjects` instead of `sys.objects`, failure to set the current database of the connection to `DataBaseName` before querying `dbo.sysobjects` which will return objects from the default database rather than `DataBaseName`? I've probably missed some.

Comment: @GSerg I'm not the one to say that to, but I'm also aware of that..

Comment: but my script now is worked !!

Comment: @NevergiveupNever Luck and confidence have done wonders in the IT world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a typo happened in this line:

```
Dim objtables As TableCollection = server.Databases(DataBaseName).Tables // change DataBaseName to combodata 

Public Sub GetTable(ByVal combodata As ComboBox, ByVal listtable As DataGridView)
    'Try
    dt.Clear()
    Dim ServerConnection As ServerConnection = Nothing
    If combodata.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("You Do Not Choose The DataBase Name", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim objCn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    ServerConnection = New ServerConnection(objCn)
    Dim server As New Server(ServerConnection)
    Dim objtables As TableCollection = server.Databases(combodata).Tables
    If objtables.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You Do Not Choose The DataBase Name", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        combodata.Focus()
    End If
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT name as 'Table Name' FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'u' ORDER BY Name", objCn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    listtable.DataSource = dt
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    'End Try
End Sub

//how to call
private void dbnames_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GetTable(dbnames.text, dgv);
    }
```